# Determine the feature size in the picture

Tags: image-processing

I was doing some fractal dimension calculation using http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1025046 box counting method and I thought to myself if it would be possible to make a constrain that the boxes (or circles) have to touch at least two edges. that would be a great tool to estimate the size of the features in e.g. fibrous network from SEM images.
[image]

https://www.dropbox.com/s/0a3t8w4tv9zu9jb/agarose_analysis.jpg?dl=0

and plotting e.g. there are 40 circles of size 30px, 10 of size 29px etc.
any ideas how to implement that?

Answer (score 8):

This is relatively easy using a distance transform:

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/Juolc.png"]
binary = Binarize[img, .9];
dist = DistanceTransform[ColorNegate[binary]];
```

Now, `dist`, contains for each pixel the euclidean distance to the closest white pixel. The points you're looking for are (I think) the local maxima in this image:

```
maxPos = ComponentMeasurements[MaxDetect[dist], "Centroid"][[All, 2]];    
radii = PixelValue[dist, maxPos]
```

Which yields these circles:

```
Show[binary, Graphics[{Red, MapThread[Circle, {maxPos, radii}]}]]
```

[image]

and the radii:

```
Histogram[radii, {1}]
```

[image]

These are the circles that are locally maximal. So they're usually touching 3 or more white points. If you want all circles that touch *two* white points, you should look at `SkeletonTransform`.

For example, for a square, the method above wold yield only on circle, at the center of the square. `SkeletonTransform` would yield all points along the diagonals of the square - as circles centered on the diagonals touch the square in two places.

[image]

Comment: this is great! One question: is it possible to color code the circles on the image using e.g. rainbow colors with a legend?

Comment: @dziakku: Sure, you can get gradients (e.g. rainbow colors) using `ColorData` and create a legend using `BarLegend`

Comment: One additional comment - the code is great in it's simplicity - one good add-on is a GaussianFilter for binazing the image to reduce the noise